# PHP interval timing

Tags: php, scripting, time, intervals

I have a problem, I'm running a script and the PHP line duplicates to whatever number $num_newlines equals. This is what I am currently using:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=($num_newlines - 1); $i++) {
$tweetcpitems->post('statuses/update', array('status' => wordFilter("The item $array[$i]    has been released on Club Penguin.")));
}
```

What I want to do is have 90 second intervals between however many duplicates are made. So I'm not tweeting like 50 times within 10 seconds. What I want to do is add a 90 second interval between each tweet, please help!

Comment: Spamming twitter? How nice...

Comment: The code will only run if it detects that something has changed. It won't spam every 90 seconds, that is only if it detects more than one object. I want to change it to every 90 seconds so it won't spam.

Comment: Lol. club penguin.... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `sleep()` function:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_newlines - 1; $i ++) {
    $tweetcpitems->post('statuses/update', array('status' => wordFilter('The item ' . $array[$i] . ' has been released on Club Penguin.')));
    sleep(90);
}
```

This snippet sleeps after every tweet, also after the last one. To prevent sleeping unnecessary after the last tweet, use this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_newlines - 1; $i ++) {
    $tweetcpitems->post('statuses/update', array('status' => wordFilter('The item ' . $array[$i] . ' has been released on Club Penguin.')));

    if ($i <= $num_newlines - 1) {
        sleep(90);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. If you can set up [CRON jobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) - create a [queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29) of messages to post (in a database or file) and let a script run every 90 seconds that takes and removes one message from the queue and sends it.
2. Use [`sleep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) function inbetween sending messages. Note that you may need to increase the [time limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) (from the comments: *under Linux, sleeping time is ignored, but under Windows, it counts as execution time*).